# Powershell alias not being set from script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create workin environment (PATH and aliases) using powershell script.

```
powershell.exe -Command c:\workspace\script\profile.ps1 -NoExit
```

Inside the script, I set-up an alias:

```
Set-Alias npp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

And yet, after starting new terminal (via ConEmu), the alias is not defined (other settings like environment is set correctly).

Any tips how to set-up alias via script?

Answer (score 6):

There are two noteworthy things:

- You must specify `-Command "file"` as the **last** parameter due to the following:

  > If the value of Command is a string, Command must be the last parameter in the command , because any characters typed after the command are interpreted as the command arguments.

  Not doing so means the `-NoExit` parameter gets ignored and your newly started process immediately exits, taking all your new aliases with it.

  In other words, make sure to start PowerShell this way:

  ```
  powershell.exe -NoExit -Command c:\workspace\script\profile.ps1
  ```
- Defining aliases in a script means they are defined in the `Script` scope rather than `Global` scope as the profile does (read get-help [about_Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes) for more info).

  The trick then is to define a scope when creating the alias:

  ```
  Set-Alias npp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" -Scope Global
  ```

  Now the alias should be usable as soon as the script has run.

Comment: Scope global does the trick if you are using scripts which call other scripts.

Comment: I tried to use `Get-Alias` to output the content of the `Description`, but I didn’t get any content. However, after adding `-Scope Global`, it can be displayed normally. Thank you.
`Set-Alias mh MyHelp -Description "Help Message" -Scope Global` and then `(Get-Alias mh).Description` work!

Answer (score 0):

That's what [profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx) are for. Create a file `profile.ps1` in your profile directory (`$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`) and put the alias definition there. The profile is read whenever you start a PowerShell or ISE instance.

Aliases you define in a regular script are volatile, i.e. they exist only as long as the PowerShell process running the script exists.

Comment: I though so but I want to avoid using profile. Scripts have to be signed. Certificate is owned by admin and standard user has encrypted home folder. This boils down to inability to sign profile file.

Comment: I'm confused. How is signing an issue for scripts in `$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`, but not for scripts in `C:\workspace\script`?

Answer (score 0):

Just to show easier way to edit or create your profile

```
notepad $profile
```

If the profile script was not created before - just call

```
new-item -itemtype file -path $profile
notepad $profile
```